# fxDataGrid doesn't render

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have an issue with rendering fxDataGrid using Knockout. I've already asked everyone I know and searched the Web, but I didn't find any solution. Here's the problem.

I have a HTML file for rendering UI. The code is as follows:

```
﻿<div id="biab-power-user">
<div data-bind="if: isPowerUser">
    <header>
        <h2>Boxes in use</h2>
    </header>
    <div id="tenant-power-user-box-grid"></div>
    <div data-bind="if: boxRemoveVisible">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: removeBox">Decommision <span data-bind="text: selectedBoxName"></span></button>
        <div data-bind="if: showDecommissioningWarning">
            <p>
                Are you sure you want to decommision <span data-bind="text: selectedBoxName"></span> box?
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Yes" data-bind="click: handleDecommissionBox" /> <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="No" data-bind="click: cancelRemoveBox" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="validation">
        <span style="color: red" data-bind="visible: !!actionError, text: actionError"></span>
    </section>
</div>
<div data-bind="ifnot: isPowerUser">
    <section class="validation">
        <span style="color: red">You are not allowed to view the content of this page.</span>
    </section>
</div>
```

Then I have an underlying JS controller for the code, which has several functions that should bind the data:

```
...
var fxGridSelector = "#tenant-power-user-box-grid";
var isGridDrawn = false;
...
function loadBoxes() {
    controller.getTenantBoxes().then(function (success) {                
            setGridData(success);
            clearBoxActions();
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function drawGrid(gridData) {
    $(fxGridSelector).fxDataGrid({
        coulmns: [
            { name: "Name", field: "Name" },
            { name: "Project", field: "ProjectName" },
            { name: "Team", field: "Team" },
            { name: "Owner", field: "Owner" },
            { name: "GI Version", field: "GoldenImageVersionName" }
        ],
        selectable: true,
        multiselect: false,
        rowSelect: onRowSelect,
        data: gridData,
        noRows: "There are no boxes in use."
    });

    isGridDrawn = true;
}

function setGridData(gridData) {
    if (!isGridDrawn) {
        drawGrid(gridData);
        return;
    }

    $(fxGridSelector).fxDataGrid({
        data: gridData
    });
}
...
```

The rest of the JS isn't relevant to the problem. I've checked, and the JSON is properly returned from the REST call. According to the documentation and what I found, that code should work. Moreover, I have almost identical code in different sections of the UI (it differs only in the data rendered) and it works. However, in this particular HTML the data just doesn't want to render.

Can You help me with this? I'd be grateful. :)

Comment: Are you seeing the "Boxes in use" header at least, as opposed to the "You are not allowed to view..." message, meaning that you're sure isPowerUser is true?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of that REST data for reproduction purposes?